# Firefox renders bad with interlaced images?

Tags: firefox, browser, cross-browser

I'm converting all the images on my website to interlaced, but i found a possible issue, under *OSX 10.10.5 and Firefox 38.0.5*

Interlaced PNGs that are bigger than the browser window (and so they are resized in automatic by the browser) display in a very low quality, like if they are displayed in one of the intermediate layers, and not in the final version. Zooming the image to 100% removes the problem, and changing the browser windows size removes the problem as well.

Here is an example of an interlaced image:

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/attachment/ticket/161/Test_24bpp_interlaced_paeth.png

(you have to download it and open with firefox in a small window, so that the image zooms out)

This issue is happening in the 80% of the times I try the same operation.

The issue doesn't appear, instead, in jpeg progressive images.

Could you please confirm me the issue? I think it's very strange that I can't find any other people having my same problem.